# How to handle action method in Partial view using Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have header view there is I am using the partial view for add search. But when I click on search button then I am getting following error

```
The controller for path '/api/sitecore/Registration/Search' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

How can call action method by the partial view in sitecore.

Comment: You should make sure that you have registered the route

Comment: What is your controller called? What is the action called?  Can you post the code to render the link? Are you using razor?